# AutoLayout puzzling constraints error

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, visual-format-language

I'm trying to add a subview on a Custom Navigation Bar.
The Custom Navigation Bar is being used so that the bar height is increased to fit in the extra subview.

The problem is I'm trying to use AutoLayout for adding the new view, and when I add a VFL Horizontal constraint to my new view I get an error in the NSLog about "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints", which I don't understand.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    UIView *loadingView = [UIView new];
    loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self addSubview:loadingView];


    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-38-[loadingView(30@1000)]"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loadingView)]];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[loadingView]-|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loadingView)]];

    NSLog(@"CONSTRAINTS:%@",self.constraints);
```

And this the eror i'm getting on the log file:

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad422d0 UIView:0x7ad412c0.leading == CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad14a30 CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7ad412c0.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79e8d990 H:[CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad14a30 CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7ad412c0.trailing>
```

If I remove the standard spacing from my VFL, meaning I use :

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[loadingView]|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loadingView)]];
```

I don't get a warning.
I cannot understand why this is happening.

Also please note that the `UINavigationBar` constraints (`self.constraints`) are empty before adding my own constraints, so this doesn't cause any conflicting constraints.

I also did an NSLog on the `UINavigationBar` `self.constraints` in both cases and this is the NSLog in case 1 (no error when using VFL `H:|[loadingView]|` :

```
2014-10-15 16:35:54.894 Snapette[10984:132305] CONSTRAINTS:(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a938900 V:|-(38)-[UIView:0x7a996290]   (Names: '|':CustomNavigationBar:0x7a98d6b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a93a740 V:[UIView:0x7a996290(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a997260 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7a996290]   (Names: '|':CustomNavigationBar:0x7a98d6b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a93b7f0 H:[UIView:0x7a996290]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':CustomNavigationBar:0x7a98d6b0 )>"
)
```

While this is what I get when I use ``H:|-[loadingView]-|`

```
2014-10-15 16:37:27.140 Snapette[11037:133374] CONSTRAINTS:(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad102a0 V:|-(38)-[UIView:0x7ad412c0]   (Names: '|':CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad15690 V:[UIView:0x7ad412c0(30)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad422d0 UIView:0x7ad412c0.leading == CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ad14a30 CustomNavigationBar:0x7ad388b0.trailingMargin == UIView:0x7ad412c0.trailing>"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ac748d0 h=-&- v=--& V:[CustomNavigationBar:0x7d96ed50(76)]>"`

has the answer.

Your CustomNavigationBar has translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints == YES.  When you tell the loading view to fit inside the navbar, the navbar sizes itself and then tells the loadingView it's size. that's why your second case succeeds.  In the first case the loading view has a high priority height and then some default priority vertical spacing which all conflict with the default priority vertical spacing designated by translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints.

try:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIView *loadingView = [UIView new];
loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self addSubview:loadingView];

NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[loadingView]-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loadingView)]];

[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-38-[loadingView(30@1000)]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(loadingView)]];

[self addConstraints:constraints];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as it crashes the app: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot modify constraints for UINavigationBar managed by a controller'`

Comment: More puzzling I get a different set of constraints errors if I add the constraints one by one, instead at once from an `NSMutableArray` (see my updated question)

Comment: Well, I think the answer to your question is that you can't do what you want to do with a UINavigationBar that is being shown as part of a UINavigationController.  You probably need to rethink your design to have either header view, or for your specific view controller that is contained in the UINavigationController, hide the UINavigationController UINavigationBar and have your controller add and control it's own UINavigationBar.

Comment: The real problem that is causing your issue is the height constraint on your loading view inside of a fixed height UINavigationBar that you don't own or control: V:|-38-[loadingView(30@1000)]  this constraint says that the super view needs to be standard vertical space + 38 + standard interitem vertical space + 30 high, but the UINavigationController has the navigation bar constrained and won't let it grow that tall.

Comment: The problem is caused by the Horizontal and not Vertical constraint. And yes, if I can't solve this with AutoLayout, I'll use the old springs & sprouts layout and work with that.